# What's the difference between $< and $^ in a makefile?

Tags: linux, makefile

What is the difference between the implicit variables `$<` and `$^` in a makefile?

For example:

```
$(LIBS): $(LIB_OBJS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAG) -shared $< -o $@
```

and

```
$(LIBS): $(LIB_OBJS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAG) -shared $^ -o $@
```

It seems that the result is the same. In my case, I let $(LIBS) and $(LIB_OBJS) only have one file each.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.pdf section `10.5.3 Automatic Variables` @ the page number 120

Answer (score 5):

To quote from the GNU Make "[Automatic Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html)" page:

`$<`

The name of the first prerequisite. [...]

`$^`

The names of all the prerequisites, with spaces between them. [...]

So in your case when there is only one prerequisite there is no difference.